# Super+Tab switcher shortcut Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, unity-tweak-tool

How can I set `<Super>+<Tab>` to be my shortcut for the window switcher? I have tried using Unity Tweak Tool but **I cannot get the `Tab` key to register as part of a shortcut**. `<super>+<tab>` does not register and `<super>+<tab>+<letter>` (e.g. `<super>+<tab>+a`) registers as `<super>+<letter>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have ccsm (compiz manager) you can enable ring switch under window manager, by default it uses super+tab to change windows.

Comment: This solves the OP's problem, but it doesn't answer the question in general. It would be great if someone explained how to do it for any shortcut for any of the available actions.